# Joomla virtuemart payment plugin event before confirm

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I need virtuemart PSPlugin event for user can validate the payment data.
If i use the plgVmConfirmedOrder for it, my form is showed in the confirm page.

I need a page before "thanks for the order" page, but after user pushed the "confirm" button in the cart.

Anyone knows which method is good for this event what I need?

```
class plgVMPaymentOTPay extends vmPSPlugin
{

    function __construct (& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct ($subject, $config);

        $this->_loggable = TRUE;
        $this->tableFields = array_keys ($this->getTableSQLFields ());
        $this->_tablepkey = 'id';
        $this->_tableId = 'id';
        $varsToPush = $this->getVarsToPush ();
        $this->setConfigParameterable ($this->_configTableFieldName, $varsToPush);
    }


    public function plgVmDisplayListFEPayment(VirtueMartCart $cart, $selected = 0, &$htmlIn)
    {
        echo 'Fired: plgVmDisplayListFEPayment <br>';

        return $this->displayListFE($cart, $selected, $htmlIn);
    }

    public function plgVmOnShowOrderFEPayment ($virtuemart_order_id, $virtuemart_paymentmethod_id, &$payment_name)
    {
        echo 'Fired: plgVmOnShowOrderFEPayment <br>';

        $this->onShowOrderFE($virtuemart_order_id, $virtuemart_paymentmethod_id, $payment_name);
    }

    function checkConditions ($cart, $method, $cart_prices)
    {
        echo 'Fired: checkConditions <br>';

        return true;
    }

    public function plgVmonSelectedCalculatePricePayment(VirtueMartCart $cart, array &$cart_prices, &$cart_prices_name)
    {
        echo 'Fired: plgVmonSelectedCalculatePricePayment <br>';

        return $this->onSelectedCalculatePrice($cart, $cart_prices, $cart_prices_name);
    }

    function plgVmConfirmedOrder($cart, $order)
    {

        echo 'Fired: plgVmConfirmedOrder <br>';

    }


}
```